# h1 over canvas but unselectable/touchable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to put h1 tag over canvas but in the way that I can still click canvas behind h1 tag. Here is example im working on now [Link here](http://bartuz.github.io/180-days-180-websites/day-002/index.html). As you see you can't click canvas behind h1 tag (shoot firework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the pointer-events property to none. This will make all pointer events on `h1` elements be ignored and "pass-through" to the canvas below.

```
h1 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```